# Bidirectional RNN cells - shared or not?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

Should I use the same weights to compute forward and backward passes in a bidirectional RNN, or should those weights be learned independently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They should be learned independently as they learn different patterns, unless you have [palindromes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome). In fact that is the default in the [Bidirectional](https://keras.io/layers/wrappers/#bidirectional) wrapper in Keras:

```
self.forward_layer = copy.copy(layer)
config = layer.get_config()
config['go_backwards'] = not config['go_backwards']
self.backward_layer = layer.__class__.from_config(config)
```

In the above [source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/7205d903fbc079bb99fbae0e3c02e6d2b4d227f0/keras/layers/wrappers.py#L364) the opposite direction is a *copy* with independent weights from the original direction.

Comment: Isn't that just a shallow copy? And layer seems to be a compound object.

Answer (score 2):

It should be independently. See `expected_hidden_size` [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/rnn.html).

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I haven't seen the same set of weights being used for both forward and backward pass that often, and I find using the same set of weights for both the forward and backward pass counter intuitive.

Because the idea of the Bidirectional RNNs is to have two hidden states for each input, giving information about what should be (or is) before the current input, and what should be (or is) after the current input. You can't have such two different states for an input if you use the same shared set of weights.